# Post Ajax para Class PHP

Tags: php, ajax, orientação-a-objetos

Eu tenho o seguinte código que salva a reordenação de uma lista.

INDEX.PHP

```
<?php

    require_once ("Class.Drag.php");

    $auth_task = new Drag();

    $list_order = strip_tags($_POST['list_order']); 

    $res=$auth_task->update($list_order);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="content"> 

        <ul id="sortable">

            <?php 
                echo $auth_task->select();
            ?>
        </ul>

        </div><!-- content -->  
    </div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CLASS.DRAP.PHP

```
public function update($list_order){

    $list = explode(',' , $list_order);
    $i = 1 ;
    foreach($list as $id) {
        try {

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('UPDATE items SET item_order = :item_order WHERE id = :id');
            $stmt->bindParam(':item_order', $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

        }catch (PDOException $exception){

        header("Location: ./error.php?err=Cant-Order");
        echo 'Erro: '.$exception->getMessage();
        return null;

    }
        $i++ ;
    }

}
```

SCRIPTDRAG.JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.7,
        handle: 'span',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var list_sortable = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();         
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',                
                data: {list_order:list_sortable},
                success: function(data) {
                    success_message('Gravado');
                },
                error: function(data){
                    failure_message('Erro');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Só que meu envio do post é vazio, como eu faço para não utilizar

```
$list_order = strip_tags($_POST['list_order']); 

$res=$auth_task->update($list_order);
```

Tem algum jeito para enviar o $list_order direto para classe pelo ajax, sem precisar fazer o post no index.

Porque vai sempre aparecer **Notice: Undefined index: list_order**, pelo post vazio.

Comment: `$_POST` para gravar é correto? onde esta enviando o submit dele? não seria usar `$_GET`?

Comment: Qual o trecho de codigo que renderezia as tags `<li>` da lista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma saida seria verificar se o metodo é POST.

```
//aqui verifica o metodo do envio, GET ou POST
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //verifica se o campo 'list_order' existe no $_POST
    if(isset($_POST['list_order'])){
        $list_order = strip_tags($_POST['list_order']); 
        $res=$auth_task->update($list_order);
    }
    //mata o script para nao executar o resto do html
    exit('fim');
}
```

Alem disso pode colocar esse trecho de codigo em um script separado da index, talvez um atualizar_lista.php e chamar ele ao inves de da index no js, `url: 'atualizar_lista.php',`

Comment: é isso mesmo que eu fiz, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Na real, creio que os colegas não entenderam o problema. Segundo o texto:

> ... Só que meu envio do post é vazio, como eu faço para não utilizar ...

Supondo que o método: `<?php echo $auth_task->select(); ?>` retorne a seguinte string:

```
<li>meu item</li>
```

O problema do envio do post vazio, é porque o item da lista nao possui um id, e deveria ser assim o retorno da string do metodo:

```
<li id="123">meu item</li>
```

E o script jQuery deveria ser mais ou menos assim:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.7,
        handle: 'span',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var list_sortable = $(this).sortable('toArray');         
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                type: 'POST',                
                data: {list_order: list_sortable},
                success: function(data) {
                    success_message('Gravado');
                },
                error: function(data){
                    failure_message('Erro');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

E tranquilamente voce poderia mudar o alvo do post em: `url: 'index.php',` para qualquer outro arquivo, ex: `url: 'grava_ordenacao_items.php',`

Creio que seja isso! Espero ter ajudado.